# Calculating Leaf Area Density for different vegetation types based on height conditions

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

The `LAD` function in `lidR` is used to calculate the Leaf Area Density. This can be done as shown below. Now, how can I calculate `LAD` out of a `LAS` file for different vegetation types based on height thresholds, say, 0.3-0.5 ("herbaceous"), 0.5-2.0 (shrubs), and >2.0 ("trees") and plot them accordingly?

```r
LAD_LAS = LAD(LAS_denoised$Z,dz = 0.3,k = 0.5)
# Plot the LAD
plot(LAD_LAS , type="l", xlab="Height(meters)", ylab="LAD", main = "Leaf Area Density")
```

For example, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Please clarify.

Comment: @JRR, the purpose is to calculate LAD for different vegetation types individually by defining height thresholds.  Or maybe, if the LAS file is classified as low, medium and high vegetation, then to try and compute LAD for each vegetation class separately. Hope, this makes sense.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify. Add pictures, examples or whatever. As is I'd anwser to subset the output of `LAD` to a given threshold. But it is not obvious if it makes sense. Anyway you cannot compute the LAD with a subset of the point it does not make sense for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute a canopy height model (CHM) and then decide a height threshold that tells trees from shrubs.

The canopy height is the difference between the first lidar reflections (that come from the tops of greenery) and the reflections from the ground. The first reflections get you a DSM (digital surface model) and the ground reflections get you a DTM (digital terrain model). The difference is then your canopy height. For more:

https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/lidar-raster-data-r/lidar-chm-dem-dsm/

Then you classify your image based on a threshold canopy height. If its got high leaf density and large canopy height = trees, high leaf density & low canopy height = shrubs, low leaf density = bare ground (and should also be small or zero canopy height).